# MySQL AS Statement in DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL command, meant to select nearby objects out of a table:

```
SELECT *,3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((49 - lat)*pi()/180/2),2)+
    COS(49 * pi()/180)*COS(lat * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-127 -lng)*
    pi()/180/2),2))) AS distance 
FROM postings 
HAVING distance < 5 
ORDER BY distance;
```

Which works fine. However, I'd like to adapt the statement for deletion (`DELETE FROM postings WHERE distance < 5;`) but can't quite figure out how to do so. MySQL seems to have problems with the syntax of something like:

```
DELETE *,3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((49 - lat)*pi()/180/2),2)+
    COS(49 * pi()/180)*COS(lat * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-127 -lng)*
    pi()/180/2),2))) as distance 
FROM postings 
HAVING distance < 5 
ORDER BY distance;
```

And I can see why, as `DELETE` is usually intended to delete columns from particular rows while distance, and the `AS` statement used to create it, are not columns in the original table and are thus useless for the `DELETE` command in that spot in the syntax. I can't figure out how to edit it though.

Comment: `WHERE your_formula_here < 5`. Also remove `ORDER BY`, it's redundant.

Comment: Move calculations to `WHERE`.

Comment: `DELETE` is used to delete **rows** (not **columns**).

Comment: DELETE FROM postings WHERE .... all your stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this doesn't work because `delete` doesn't support `group by` and hence also doesn't support `having`.

One method is to move the formula to a `where` clause.  Another method is to use a `join`:

```
DELETE p
    FROM postings p JOIN
         (SELECT p.*,
                 3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((49 - lat)*pi()/180/2),2)+
    COS(49 * pi()/180)*COS(lat * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-127 -lng)*
    pi()/180/2),2))) as distance
          FROM postings
         ) pp
         on p.id = pp.id and distance < 5;
```

If you put the formula in the `where`, then it would look like this:

```
DELETE postings
    WHERE 3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((49 - lat)*pi()/180/2),2)+
    COS(49 * pi()/180)*COS(lat * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-127 -lng)*
    pi()/180/2),2))) < 5 ;
```

The `order by` doesn't make sense in the `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

using inner select query get record ids and then delete it 
to delete records you can add that distance calculation logic in where clause

```
DELETE FROM postings where id in (SELECT postid  FROM 
     postings where 3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((49 - lat)*pi()/180/2),2)+
    COS(49 * pi()/180)*COS(lat * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-127 -lng)*
    pi()/180/2),2)))   < 5 ORDER BY distance)
```